# How to use a WPF User control in a different namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, namespaces, controls, .net-assembly

I have a usercontrol outside the namespace of my program, in the XAML design editor the usercontrols work, yet the compiler sees problems:

```
<Window x:Class="SNMP_Printer_Monitor.Windows.SettingsWindow"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:HDTools.Michiel.UserControls"
>

// Further down the line in a grid:
<controls:UCMailList x:Name="MailWarningList" Margin="610,180,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="246" Height="259"/>
```

The Usercontrol is made in HDTools.Michiel.UserControls named UCMailList. The Window is in SNMP_Printer_Monitor.Windows.SettingsWindow;

The error is get:

```
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'UserControls' does not exist in the namespace 'SNMP_Printer_Monitor.HDTools.Michiel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   SNMP Printer Monitor    C:\Users\info\source\repos\Michiel\SNMP Printer Monitor\SNMP Printer Monitor\Windows\SettingsWindow.xaml    34  Active
```

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Is `UCMailList` in the same assembly as `SettingsWindow`? If not you need to add the assembly name. Something like `xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:HDTools.Michiel.UserControls;assembly=MyOtherAssembly"`. Also make sure it's public.

Comment: Also make sure the main project references the library assembly.

Comment: @Lennart, the assembly is called SNMP Printer Monitor from the main program, the Usercontrol is just in HDTools.Michiel.Usercontrols. A package I reuse in different applications. It does not have a assembly name... also when I try assembly=SNMP Printer Monitor, it gives me errors...